# In my phonegap app, I'm trying to upload a file from device to remote server. Error code =1

Tags: php, cordova, file-upload, file-transfer, phonegap

In my PhoneGap app, I'm trying to upload a file from device to remote server. 
I checked on the file details in the device.

I got the fileURL from this:
[image: Screenshot]

*Error code=1*

```
var fileURL=filePath;   //output file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/xport1.csv
var uri = encodeURI("http://www.example.com/upload/upload.php");
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);  // output  xport1.csv

options.mimeType = "text/plain";
options.chunkedMode = true;

var headers = {'headerParam':'headerValue'};
options.headers = headers;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, uri, onSuccess, onError, options,true);
```

I am getting an error has occurred code=1.

In my php file , `print_r($_FILES);`

How do i get the file url? The file will always be placed in Download folder.

Please help. There are many examples for uploading image but not for other file types.

---

Update from comment:

```
function upload() {
  filePath = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/xport1.csv';
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(filePath, onResolveSuccess, fail);
}

function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
  var fileURL = filePath;
  var uri = encodeURI('http://www.example.com/upload/upload.php');
  var opt = new FileUploadOptions();
  ft.upload(fileURL, uri, onSuccess, onErr, opt, true);
}
```

Comment: You may have no permission to read files in the download-folder in this way. Have you already tried to make an request to the download-folder by using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL before trying to upload the file? In this way you can also check whether the file exists or going to the file by using adb shell-commands. Good luck!

Comment: I used  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL .on success, upload starts .   function upload()
     {
     filePath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/xport1.csv";

     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(filePath, onResolveSuccess, fail);
     }
 function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
 var fileURL=filePath;
     var uri = encodeURI("http://www.example.com/upload/updSchedule.php");
     var opt = new FileUploadOptions();
     ft.upload(fileURL, uri, onSuccess, onErr, opt,true);
     }

Comment: You can also try 1. to put http:// into encodeURI at the beginning of the URL and 2. removing the paramaters opt and trustAllHosts as they are not helping you right now and for trustAllHosts I know, it's convenient at this stage, but it only delays the inevitable struggle with certificates. The problem can also be with the server-configuration so you can also try to upload a file via html-form to check it.

Comment: The code has http. but it is not shown after posting. i dont know. var uri = encodeURI("http://www.example.com/upload/updSchedule.php"); When I try to change the actual url, omission happened.  my apologies

Comment: Ok, no problem :) Please insert any news into your question or make an answer to show what helped you to solve this issue. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry u are mistaken. the issue is not resolved. in my original code itself. i did have the entire url ( full path with http:// www) but they are not shown in the post.  Now to your suggestions i tried both. but nothing works..

Comment: Sorry for being mistaken. The last suggestion I can give you is to insert/move this *.csv file into your app-folder: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE_HERE . Hope this helps otherwise good luck!